# How can I check if a key/value pair exists in php?

Tags: php

I am getting a list of schools for each athlete. If an athlete has a status of `committed: true` in the object, I only want to show that school. Otherwise, I want to return all properties.

This is what my data looks like:

```
...
"offers": [
    {
        "school": "Foo School",
        "committed": true
      },
      {
        "school": "Bar School",
        "committed": false
      }
    ]
...
```

In the above example, I only want to show "Foo School".
But if both `committed` properties were `false` I want to show "Foo Schoo" *and* "Bar School".

Here is what I have currently, but am returning both regardless.

```
foreach ($object['athlete']['offers'] as $offer) {
    if (isset($offer['committed']) && $offer['committed'] == 1) {
       // return single school
    } else {
       // push into array & return?
    }
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: If any offer in the offers array has a property of `committed:true` only return that offer. Otherwise return all offers in the array.

Comment: Is it possible that it's the mixed array / object causing conflict? you may need the syntax of `$offer->committed`. Are you using `json_decode()` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for, please correct me if I'm wrong. If all of them are false, then it returns all.  If one or more are true, it returns the first one that's true:

```
<?php

$offers = array(
    array("school" => "Foo School",
    "committed" => true
  ),
  array(
    "school" => "Bar School",
    "committed" => false
  ));

$fullReturn = "";
$flag = false;
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    if (isset($offer['committed']) && $offer['committed']) {
       echo $offer['school'];
       $flag = true;
       break;
    } else {
       $fullReturn .= $offer['school'] . "<br />";
    }
}

if (!$flag) {
    echo $fullReturn;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, @nfn neil! I was missing the `break`; Because I didn't have that - the system kept going and returned all results no matter what.

Comment: `break` doesn't effect anything ! setting global variable is the main reason @Damon

Comment: I added the break to prevent it from echoing the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two array and you want to check if the $haystack array have minimum $needle array's element and they match or not then you can use that function

```php
    function array_match($needle, $haystack){
        $haystack =  (array) $haystack;
        $needle =  (array) $needle;
        foreach ($needle as $key => $value) {
            if( trim($value) != trim($haystack[$key]) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```